# Best practice to share google drive API credentials for being used by a script?

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-drive-shared-drive

***In a nutshell:*** Shall I share oauth2-credentials in our source code with the scope of full write-access to a google drive from a dedicated single-purpose google-account?

so, I've written a python script which saves some data into either a pre-existing google-sheets file or creates a new google-sheets file into a given google drive folder (both of which are publicly editable for sharing purpose between teams).

For this I followed the steps and tutorials outlined by [google](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) and other sources whereafter I have obtained oauth2-credentials needed for my script to be authenticated with the google drive and google sheets API.

Those credentials are derived from a single-purpose google-account which I have created for this script.

Now I would like to share this script with other team-members but am unsure about how to proceed regarding the credentials; either:

**A.)**

> I would incorporate the suggested google workflow which would let the
>   user of the script authenticate him/herself, i.e. the user starts the
>   script, then is directed to the google-authentication weblogin,
>   authenticates the script, and then the script would save and use those
>   credentials of the user for writing data into a public google-sheets
>   file (not necessarily a private one owned by the user).

This has the downsides that:

- the user would trust my script with credentials which could enable it
  to read/write all of the data of the user's drive account. While I do
  not mean any harm of course, it still seems rather too much to ask
  and be responsible for
- it breaks the intended straight-forward workflow of my script.
- is not necessary at all technically, because the script shall only
  write into public sheets-files / drive folders; so why should it need
  write-access to all the user's drive files?.

**B.)**

> hardcode the credentials of our single-purpose account into the
>   script; which has the only downside that when the script's source code
>   would be shared, that anyone could obtain those credentials. But these
>   credentials would only enable an attacker to write/read data into the
>   account's google drive, but not take control over the whole account
>   itself due to the limitations of the scope of the oauth2 credentials
>   (I've used the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" [scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)).
>   Additionally, as said before, we would only use the script to
>   read/write data into public sheets-files which are owned by real
>   google-accounts, so never would we use the drive of the single-purpose
>   account and thus no attacker could destroy our data.

Thus, I am rather opting for option B, but I can't help the anxiety which comes from hardcoding publicly readable credentials...

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We decided for option A: users need to create client_secret.json and credentials.json files themselves. It is unfortunately not the most straight forward, but the most secure one. Sharing credentials in a public repo is just a big no-go, no matter the details.

Also for the sake of completeness: another alternative would be to have our application running on a server where we could save the client_secret, so then a user would just be presented with a browser-popup where he/she would authorize our service.

But we don't follow that option either since the script shall only contain the core logic and it shall be a base for other to develop upon.

That's our motivation behind the decision.